# Suppose $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds and $F:M\to N$ a smooth map. Assume that $dF_p:T_pM \to T_{F(p)}N$ is the zero map. Show that $F$ is constant

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> Suppose $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds and $F:M\to N$ a smooth map. Assume that $dF_p:T_pM \to T_{F(p)}N$ is the zero map for each $p \in M$. Show that $F$ is constant.

Letting $(U,\varphi)$ to be a chart on $M$ and $(V, \psi)$ be a chart on $N$ I have the coorindate representation $\hat{F}:=\psi \circ F \circ \varphi^{-1}:\varphi(U \cap F^{-1}(V)) \to \psi(V)$.

Lee, then suggests that $dF_p( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \bigg|_p)=\frac{\partial \hat{F}}{\partial x^i} (\hat{p})\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j} \bigg|_{F(p)}$, but if the differential is the zero map, then $$dF_p( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \bigg|_p)=\frac{\partial \hat{F}}{\partial x^i} (\hat{p})\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j} \bigg|_{F(p)}=0.$$

How does this imply that $\hat{F}$ would be constant? I'm considering an arbitary basis vector under the differential, but what if I considered something otherthan a basis vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set of partial derivatives $\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}\right|_{F(p)}$ is a basis of $T_{F(p)}N$. If the linear combination $$\frac{\partial \hat{F}}{\partial x^i} (\hat{p})\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j} \bigg|_{F(p)}=0$$ is the zero vector, then all coefficients $\frac{\partial \hat{F}}{\partial x^i} (\hat{p})$ must be zero. You should note that $dF_p$ is the zero map in the chart containing $p$, so you can remove the dependence from $p$ in the chart and $\frac{\partial \hat{F}}{\partial x^i}=0$ in the open set $\varphi(U \cap F^{-1}(V))$, hence $\hat{F}$ is constant here (for this statement you need $\varphi(U \cap F^{-1}(V))$ connected but you can restrict this to the connected component containing $p$). Can you conclude from here?

Answer (score 1):

You need $M$ to be connected for the result to hold. If two points $x$ and $y$ are close enough, you can work in coordinate charts and you are reduced to the case of a map between ${\bf R}^n$ to ${\bf R}^m$. There it follows from a standard estimate that comes from the Taylor expansion.